The reasoning behind the buoyancy force equation
If I drop a block in water, the pressure experienced on the top of the block is the $\rho gh$. That is because a certain amount of water is distributing a force above the block.
I don't understand why the pressure at the bottom of the block is equal to $\rho g \times\text{depth of the bottom part}$. Why depth at the bottom part? There is no extra water on top of the block, so to me it would make more sense to set the force at the bottom to be equal to the force of the water on top of the block plus the weight of the block itself. But that obviously can't be the case because the block is sinking. I need some help with this.

Your problem is an extremely common beginner's question on the topic. Have you read a textbook on it or something? Many treatments will be woeful, but you should be able to find great treatments.

Hint: what has the block displaced to make room for itself?
